# magento login not works unless variens cookie parameter are disabled on core file

Tags: cookie, admin-login

I couldn't login to magento dashboard unless commenting these codes

```
   $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        //'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        //'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        //'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );
```

My admin values look like below[image]

Comment: remove comment from code..then delete all cookie record from db 's core_config_data table using delete  from core_config_data where path like '%cookie%'

Comment: Thanks for your comments, .. I removed comments and deleted rows look like %cookie% path. still its not working

Comment: try At another browswer

Comment: Tried on chrome, safari and Firefox and nothing works !!!

Comment: I doubt base url not redirects, will that be a case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorted out the issue somehow,

Reverted back original Varien.php.
deleted rows look like %cookie%, %web/secure/base%, %web/unsecure/base% path from core_config_data.
deleted local cookies.
deleted var/cache and var/session folders

logged in again as fresh everything works fine now..

Hope it should help someone.

Comment: Deleting `var/session` is never an appropiate solution. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94589/keeping-customers-logged-in-after-deleting-var-session